# AutoHotKey script to automatically close a window when it opens

Tags: windows-7, autohotkey

How can I use AutoHotKey to automatically close a pop up window called ***Microsoft Office Wizard*** every time it pops up.  The window can be closed using Alt+F4 or by clicking on a Close button.
I'd like this script to be running in the background and close the pop up every time it opens.
Many thanks

Comment: Well sort of, I'm a newbie at this, I'm afraid. Came up with IfWinExist, Microsoft Office Wizard
{
    WinActivate  ; Automatically uses the window found above.
    Send, {Alt Down}{F4}
}

Comment: But I need to have it running automatically so that the script is sent every time this window pops up

Comment: Take a look at **WinWait** or **WinWaitActive**. If required you can use it inside a loop so it runs continuously, waiting for the window and closing it every time it pops up.

Comment: Thanks Karan, I just googled WinWait and it is indeed what I am looking for - where would it go in the script?

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for!!  Simple when you know how, think I may be bitten by the bug !!  Thanks again, much appreciated

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A script like the following will kill Notepad as soon as it is opened to create a new document:

```
Loop
{
    WinWait, Untitled - Notepad
    WinClose, Untitled - Notepad
}
```

Replace the **WinTitle** parameters for [**WinWait**](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinWait.htm) and [**WinClose**](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinClose.htm) as required.

Comment: I had been doing this with `IfWinExists` with a loop and a sleep, but yours is more compact, +1. Wondering how often `WinWait` polls.

Comment: @zx81 The [WinWait](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinWait.htm) function has a `Seconds` parameter which is 0.5s by default.